# Get sql result in a c# class or function

Tags: c#, sql

i am using the same sql query in many places.

I would like to put my sql query in a c# class or a function and then, call 
the function, How can i do this ? and how can i call this function later,

thanks.

my code:

```
con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select top(1) Image_path from Images", con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Image1.Src = dr["Image_path"].ToString();
        Image2.Src = dr["Image_path"].ToString();
    }
    con.Close();
```

Comment: Do you know how to create a class?  Do you know how to create a method?  Do you know how to call any method?  Where in this problem are you stuck?  It sounds like you simply need to go read an introductory programming book or tutorial.

Comment: you should put the result in a datatable and return that

Comment: i know how to get the result from the db, i don't know how to create this code into a function so when i will have it once i will be able to use it again to avoid duplicate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static List<ImageClass> GetImages()
{
   var objList = new List<ImageClass>();
   string connectionString = "yourConnection";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (var command = new SqlCommand("Select top(1) Image_path from Images", con))
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                 objList.Add(new ImageClass()
                                   {
                                      Src = reader["Image_path"].ToString()
                                   });
                 objList.Add(new ImageClass()
                                   {
                                      Src = reader["Image_path"].ToString()
                                   });
            } 
        }

    }
      return objList ;
}
```

When you need it

```
var imageList = GetImages();
```